# Understanding this object-less JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, store

I need to parse a strange JSON looking like this

```
[
  "selectedProduct",
  "GGHJHG",
  "productsOrder",
  [
      "GGHJHG"
  ],
  "productsList",
  [
      "^ ",
      "GGHJHG",
      [
          "^ ",
          "account",
          [
              "^ ",
              "display_account_number",
              "12345",
```

It's mostly readable text, but there are tons of strings like `"^ "`, `"^1"`, `"^10"`, `"^S"`, ...

There's no single object there, just arrays, while the meaning of the above snippet is something like

```
{
"selectedProduct": "GGHJHG",
"productsOrder": [
      "GGHJHG"
  ],
"productsList": [
      "GGHJHG": {
          "account": {
              "display_account_number": "12345",
```

It's called INITIAL_STATE and is used by an react app. I'd bet, this is some well-known format used by a state-managing tool (redux or an alternative).

Does anybody know this format? Unfortunately, I've been asked not to reveal more details, but for someone using such a tool, the given information surely suffice.

Comment: Interesting. Can you see what INITIAL_STATE is used for in the code?

Comment: @Tholle I only get the minified code... too much work to debug, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ouch. Perhaps you could find some key piece of information by opening up the script in the developer tools and pretty printing it just to see where it is being used initially.